# Stuck on SQL query to count rows

Tags: sql, count, aggregate

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS TotalUserVotes
FROM tblArticleVotes AS v 
INNER JOIN tblArticles AS a 
  ON v.ArticleID = a.ID 
     AND a.AuthorID = 13405
```

This always returns 0.  I have a table `tblArticles` which has an `AuthorID` and `ID` (primary key for article).

I then have an article votes table, with an `articleID` column.

Given user `13405` I need to find out how many votes they have across all of their articles!

Just to confirm, there is currently one record in `tblArticleVotes` which has the articleID of `5`.  Article ID 5 has the author ID of 13405.

Comment: Are you sure that there are any rows in `tblArticles` with the right author id and at least one vote? You might want to add some sample data rows to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm... the AuthorID in the JOIN looks odd... maybe this works better?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalUserVotes
  FROM tblArticleVotes AS v INNER JOIN
  tblArticles AS a ON v.ArticleID = a.ID
  WHERE a.AuthorID = 13405
```

Comment: how is this different than the original query? other than the symantics of the sql statement, shouldn't they execute to the same result set?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the "AND" to "WHERE":

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalUserVotes
FROM tblArticleVotes AS v INNER JOIN
tblArticles AS a ON v.ArticleID = a.ID WHERE a.AuthorID = 13405
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your query.  To trouble shoot this break the query up.

```
DECLARE @ArticleID int
SELECT @ArticleID = a.ID FROM tblArticles a WHERE a.AuthorID=13405

PRINT @ArticleID
SELECT * FROM tblArticleVotes where ArticleID=@ArticleID
```

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

```
SELECT a.AuthorID, COUNT(v.id) as votes
FROM tblArticles AS a 
LEFT JOIN tblArticleVotes AS v ON a.ID = v.ArticleID
GROUP BY a.ID
WHERE a.AuthorID = :author_id
```